# Using AWK to pull multiple rows

Tags: linux

For example if I have a file with multiple rows and columns is it possible to pull specific rows and columns?

for example

```
1 4/8/2016 4/7/2016 4/6/2016
2 john_doe jane_doe sarah_test
3 26 45 20
4 4/8/2015 6/8/2016 8/26/2016
5 5:15 2:30 6:00
```

Desired Output

```
1 4/8/2016 4/7/2016 4/6/2016
2 john_doe jane_doe sarah_test
4 4/8/2015 6/8/2016 8/26/2016
```

Comment: what is the selection criteria for rows and columns?

Comment: No criteria other than they are the requested rows. I've used awk 'NR == 1, NR == 3' but that will print 1-3 and not allow further arguments.

Comment: That doesn't answer @MelBurslan's question.  What criteria makes them "selected rows"?  I had to guess for my answer.  and that guess is likely to be wrong, or only work for the sample you provided but not for your real data.

Comment: There is no pattern that can match those 3 lines of output and ONLY those 3 lines, so the only way to do is by specifying which line numbers are to be printed (lines 1, 2, and 4).  BTW, your date format is ambiguous, you should use the ISO standard of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Are the numbers at the start of each of your input lines actually part of the input or are you trying to indicate line numbers? Are you trying to select specific line numbers? Please edit your question to make this absolutely clear otherwise you are just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: And you should specify if these files are going to be large, with large numbers of contiguous or randomly distributed selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** it is possible to pull specific rows and columns.

This concludes answering the exact question you asked.

---

However, let me offer some general advice:

`awk` is built on a simple condition—action model.

Provide a condition and then provide an action to go with that condition.

Let's say the condition is "third row" and the action is "print the first two fields of that row."  This would look like:

```
awk 'NR==3 {print $1, $2}'
```

Let's say the condition is "Row contains the letter 'a'" and the action is "Print the whole row."

```
awk '/a/ {print}'
```

Since printing the whole row is such a common action, it is the default action:

```
awk '/a/'
```

Let's say the condition is "every row" and the action is "print the second field".  You can omit the condition:

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

For more, [read a proper tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: If I am reading this correctly i would want to use awk 'NR==3 {print $1, $2}' and just brute force the rest in a script with all the rows wanted.

Comment: @Vithar91, well for the output you specified, you could use `awk 'NR==1;NR==2;NR==4'` but you might as well just use `sed`: `sed -e 3d -e 4q filename` or `sed -n '1p;2p;4p'`.  There is a [tutorial for `sed` as well](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  If you're just *selecting* lines, you don't need `awk` (use `sed` instead), but your "brute force" job, whatever it is, can very definitely be done in `awk`.  `sed` is the assembly language of text processing; `awk` is the command line spreadsheet.

Comment: (Reposted comment to fix link.)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2 ~ /^[abd]$/ { print $2, $3, $4 }'
```

for lines where the second field is `a`, `b`, or `d`, print the second, third, and fourth fields.

You weren't at all specific on your selection criteria so I had to guess based on the difference between the input and the output you provided.

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear the columns can contain numbers, dates, names, anything really as this file has a lot of information

Comment: That ***still*** isn't helpful information.

Comment: if you expect anyone to be able to provide a better answer, you need to provide better, more detailed information.  we can't magically see your real data or read your mind to know what it is you want.

Comment: but my answer is a specific example of a generic answer that can be adapted to many situations:  `if the current line (or a field in the current line) matches a regular expression, then print some or all of the fields`.